# Get largest key with largest value in python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

How can I get the largest key with the largest value in python dictionary. In the below example you can see 1 and 2 have same frequency. But i want to return the larger key.

```
nums = [1,2,2,3,1]
frq = {}
        
        for i in nums:
            if i not in frq:
                frq[i] = 1
            else:
                frq[i] += 1
        
        frequency = max(frq, key=frq.get)
        print(frequency)
```

Comment: Note, for this usecase you could use [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)  `frq = Counter(nums)`

Answer (score 3):

Have your `key` function return a tuple of the value and the associated key.  The first element of the tuple is compared first, the second will break ties.

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> nums = [1, 2, 2, 3, 1]
>>> frq = Counter(nums)
>>> max(frq, key=lambda n: (frq[n], n))
2
```

Note that `collections.Counter` builds the `frq` dictionary automatically given `nums`.

Comment: Or we can use `max` without overriding its default `key` argument this way: `frequency = max((v, k) for k, v in Counter(nums).items())[1]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use tuple comparison for the keys to compare keys based on their frequencies, and then tiebreak based on the actual value of the key only if the frequencies are the same:

```py
frequency = max(frq, key=lambda x: (frq.get(x), x))
```

With this change, this outputs:

```py
2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, which sorts first on frequency and then on key:

```py
nums = [1,2,2,3,1]
frq = {}
        
for i in nums:
    if i not in frq:
        frq[i] = 1
    else:
        frq[i] += 1
        
frequency = max(frq, key=lambda x: (frq.get(x), x))
print(frequency)
```

Output:

```
2
```

Alternatively, you can use the Counter data type from Python's collections module to do some of the work for you:

```py
from collections import Counter
nums = [1,2,2,3,1]
frequency = max(Counter(nums).items(), key=lambda x: (x[1], x[0]))[0]
print(frequency)
```

Here we pass items() to max(), so that both the key and the value are available to the key function (lambda). The result of max() will now be a (key, value) tuple, so we use `[0]` to get just the key as our result.

**UPDATE**: One other way to do it without overriding the default `key` argument to `max()` is this:

```py
frequency = max((v, k) for k, v in Counter(nums).items())[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

First, if you find yourself in trouble, try to find the simplest solution. Then, you can optimize it, in terms of efficiency or readability(or in pythonic ways in very few lines of code).

Thus, the simplest is to:

1. Find largest value
2. Find the larger key of the ones with the largest value.

```py
nums = [1,2,2,3,1]
d = Counter(nums)
max_val = max(d.values())
max_key = max([key for key, value in d.items() if value == max_val])
```